# JavaScript: default object's properties and methods

Tags: javascript

As you know, in javascript functions  are objects, my problem is with the following code:

```
function Car() {
 this.color = "black";
}
console.log(Car.name);
console.log(Car.color);
```

**Output**: Car undefined

Since I could access **name** property of Car object why can't I access **color** property of Car object in the same way.

Another example:

```
console.log("Hello".charAt.name);
console.log("Hello".charAt.length);
```

**Output** : charAt 1

Here **charAt** is a method of String object but I used its name as a reference to access **name** and **length** properties and not only these properties but also some methods such as : **hasOwnProperty** and **isPrototypeOf**

My question is what exactly those properties and methods?

Comment: Because `color`  is set at the _construction_  time to the object of the type `Car` and is not a property of the type itself. ( `carObj = new Car(); console.log(carObj.color);` )

Comment: How do you expect to access stuff inside the function if you don't even execute the function?  The line `this.color = "black";` is never ever execute. If you do a `console.dir(Car)` you can see which properties function have.

Comment: Read the docs! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Function_prototype_object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods

Answer (score 2):

In class terms, `name` is a property of the class `Car` whereas `color` is a property of an instance of the class `Car`. You can only access the `color` property when you create a new instance of it.

```js
function Car() {
  this.color = "black"; 
}
var car = new Car()
document.write(Car.name +'<br>');
document.write(car.color +'<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your first example you're trying to access the property `color` of `function Car`;

```js
function Car() {
 this.color = "black";
console.log(this)//Window {}
};

/*you need to set Car.color */
Car.color = 'white';
console.log(Car.name);//Car
console.log(Car.color);//white

Car();

console.log(color)//black


//Car
//white
//Window {}
//black
```

while name property is set automatically in function declarations..

when called normally, in a non strict situation, `this` inside the function refers to Window object ( which is global on browser );

---

on the other hand if you call the function as a constructor `this` refers to return object:

```js
function Car() {
 this.color = "black";
console.log(this)   //object instance assigned to mazda
};
 var mazda = new Car();
console.log(mazda.color)
```